# How do you install Firefox plugins from a file?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser-addons

I would like to install this [SQLite Manager plug-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) for Firefox on Mac OS X. However, the page advertising the plug-in does not offer the customary "get addon" link (or whatever it's called). There is only the possibility of downloading files.

Such as:

[SQLiteManager_0.5.0b5.xpi](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/downloads/list)

How do you use that to install the plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I believe you just drag-and-drop it to the addons window.</s> Not on a Mac at least, though.

However, it also works on PC when you go to File -> Open and locate the XPI file.  Does that work on a Mac?

Comment: Sorry. Long day. Drag and drop didn't work. Had zero effect. Any other way to do it?

Comment: @Ethan - Ammended my response.

Answer (score 9):

All you have to do is open the file in Firefox. The installation will then start (you may have to allow it by clicking `yes` or `ok` on a bar that appears on top).

Either go File -> Open, or drag the file into the address bar, etc.

Comment: This no longer works in recent versions of Firefox (e.g. 76). I get an error "This add-on could not be installed because it has not been verified".

Answer (score 1):

Just double-click the XPI file from the Finder.

Comment: That didn't work for some reason. Thanks, for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also drag-and-drop the link into the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

I actually like [Mr. Tech Local Install](http://www.mrtech.com/extensions/index.html#toolkit) to do it, because in addition to install from file, it overrides version check etc...